# Using OpenCorporates API to return officers of a company

Tags: api, opencorporates

I have a list of a few thousand company LLC names and jurisdictions from states around the US. I would like to use the OpenCorporates API to search for the company in the relevant jurisdiction and return the names of the company’s officers (I realize that the officer's data is not available in every jurisdiction).

From the API documentation and a little testing, it seems like this isn’t currently possible. The “GET companies/search” call returns much of the information I’m interested in, but not the officers for the company. And “GET officers/search” doesn’t allow me to input the company name or ID as a parameter.

Has anyone been successful in getting officer names by searching company name or ID? I've been using the following case as an example:

Company page (has officer info): https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/05217588

API (no officer info):
https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q=28+beer+road&jurisdiction_code=gb

API documentation is here: https://api.opencorporates.com/documentation/API-Reference

Answer (score 1):

the correct form of consulting data officers from API Open Corporates:

https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/us_fl/L08000108987?api_token=Your_API_Token

URI:

- Base -> https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/jurisdiction_code/company_number?api_token=Your_API_Token